# DataRequest / DataReceived on Popover

Tags: sapui5

I have a relativ simple scenario where I have one main view having an upload collection with several entries. Each entry in the upload collection has a link which can be clicked. If I now click the link, an event is fired and I would like to show a popover including a message view.

In the click handler for the link, I receive the current context for the upload collection line and bind the element for my popover. Both popover and message view were already created in the onInit function of the view.

As I now want to show a busy indicator on the popover or the messageview, I thought to use the events "dataRequested" or "dataReceived" to set the busy indicator. However, both events seems not to be fired. I can see that a batch$ requested is sent to the backend.

I'm using an oDatamodel 2.0 and have two-way binding. I already debugged the bindElement method and it seems both event handlers are registered correctly.

Is anyone having an idea why this is not working? I have implemented something similar before and I could not understand what is the difference now. Thank you in advance for any hint.

Best regards,
Andreas

```js
var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
var oContext = oSource.getBindingContext();
            
this._oPopover.bindElement({
    path: oContext.getPath(),
    events:  
    {
    dataRequested: function () {
         this.oMessageView.setBusy(true);
    },
    dataReceived: function (e) {
         this.oMessageView.setBusy(false);
    }.bind(this)
}
});
this._oPopover.openBy(oSource);
```

Comment: Did you check your network tab? I suppose that maybe due some caching no requests are issued

Comment: This seems kind of redundant. You can simply do `this._oPopover.setBindingContext(oContext)`. And since the data is already loaded (otherwise the context woldn't exist) you probably don't need the busy indicator at all. The events are only fired if there is a real network request.